# How do I fill in this hole in my ceiling around pull light?

Tags: ceiling, light, hole

I recently had my bathroom done and a new light fitting was added. I have a hole left around it where the new light fitting is smaller than the previous one. How do I fill this in please?

[image]

Comment: Clarification - that's just the pull switch isn't it? It's not a translucent cover with a light inside?

Answer (score 2):

You call the person who did it, and say "fix it". It would have been an easier job if they moved the switch four inches inwards, and then patched in a section of crown molding.

If it has to stay there - just get a load of mud (that's the American term), and smear it into the gap. It'll look ugly, but better than the big holes you have.

Comment: Problem is, once that fixture quits (hopefully in a few years if it is a decent LED, but electronics just sometimes die unexpectedly) mud or caulk or any other filler will be a pain to remove, clean up, repatch.... Far better to get it moved now.